# App Crashes when trying to update a UIImageView after modifying the RGB values for an iOS project

Tags: ios, image, image-processing

I'm trying to apply multiple effects to images. I've created a separate file to handle the effects processing that I can send a `UIImageView` to and receive a modified copy. To save processing time, I first load the image into the separate processing file and store it in memory, rather than load the image every time I want to modify it. The flow is getImageData -> modifyRGB -> displayImage. Everything works till the last step. The returned modified image is displayed on screen for a split second, then Xcode crashes with a `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`:code 1 error. I've been over the code repeatedly, and can't find the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**UPDATE WITH MORE INFO**

I'm using Xcode 4.3.1 with Automatic Reference Counting

Using Line Breaks, I can verify that the crash happens when the line **self.imageView.image = [self.imageManipulation displayImage];** is executed. The image IS updated, but then the program immediately crashes.
Using NSZombie, i get an error **-[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2cceaf80**

From my viewController I use:

```
[self.imageManipulation getImageData:self.imageView.image];
[self.imageManipulation modifyRGB];
self.imageView.image = [self.imageManipulation displayImage];
```

My ImageManipulation file consists of:

```
@implementation ImageManipulation
static unsigned char *rgbaDataOld;
static unsigned char *rgbaDataNew;
static int width;
static int height;

- (void)getImageData:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];

    width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

    rgbaDataOld = malloc(height * width * 4);
    rgbaDataNew = malloc(height * width * 4);

    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgbaDataOld, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
}

//modify rgb values 
- (void)modifyRGB
{
    for (int byteIndex = 0 ; byteIndex < width * height * 4; byteIndex += 4)
    {
        rgbaDataNew[byteIndex] = (char) (int) (rgbaDataOld[byteIndex] / 3) + 1;
        rgbaDataNew[byteIndex+1] = (char) (int) (rgbaDataOld[byteIndex+1] / 3 + 1);
        rgbaDataNew[byteIndex+2] = (char) (int) (rgbaDataOld[byteIndex+2] / 3) + 1;
        rgbaDataNew[byteIndex+3] = (char) (int) 255;
    }    
}

//set image
- (UIImage *)displayImage
{
    CGContextRef context;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgbaDataNew, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast ); 

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (context);
    UIImage *outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];  

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);    
    CGContextRelease(context);  
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return outputImage;
}

@end
```

Comment: Generally Excess_Bad_Access comes if you are accessing the data that is released or the object has no reference to it.Check your code for allocation and release on object , on which the exception comes.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is too broad. Have you set some breakpoints to narrow down when the error is thrown? Did you slide the thread list compression slider all the way over to the right in the Debug Navigator to see a larger chunk of the stack at the time the exception is thrown, or type "bt" (for "backtrace") in the lldb (or gdb) console? As roronoa said, it's probably due to trying to access something that's already been released, but some basic debugging to narrow it down will either answer it for you or at least give us enough clues to help.

Comment: I will try to narrow it down further. The crash occurs when executing the line **self.imageView.image = [self.imageManipulation displayImage];**. And, even though it crashes on that line, the darkened modified image is still displayed, but only for a split second before crashing. The **[self.imageManipulation displayImage]** method executes completely - verified with breakpoints. I will keep checking.

Comment: You seem to be using imageWithCGImage correctly... is your imageView not being retained somehow? And are you getting anything at all in the trace?

Comment: Not sure. Here is the trace error: **tid = 0x2203, 0x016ba09b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 15, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x439a0008)** which definitely seems to be an issue with sending a message to an object that's not there, or can't receive that specific message at the very least. My guess, is that the image is being updated via a link-only of some kind. Then the link is being destroyed and the program crashes. I'm not sure how to address this. Is there a way to permanently assign an image to a UIImageView that will make it independent?

Comment: Well, once the imageView owns the image then it should be able to keep ahold of it without assistance, which is why I wonder if the imageView itself is going away, or there's some other release (intentional or at the end of the runloop) that's losing track of it. I suggest turning on NSZombie and you'll be able to see what exactly is being accessed after it's gone.

Comment: My errors alternate between the one I listed above, and this one: **tid = 0x2203, 0x012c23bf CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 47, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x406894c6)**. I've tried creating a new **UIImage *newImage;** and having the **[self.imageManipulation displayImage]** send to it. This does not create any errors. But, if I then use the line **self.imageView.image = newImage;** I get the same crash again.

Comment: Definitely NSZombie, you'll see what's actually being prematurely released and where.

Comment: What happens if you skip the second step where: [self.imageManipulation modifyRGB];  See if it still crashes.

Comment: Still crashes with the same error if I skip the **[self.imageManipulation modifyRGB]** step. NSZombie reported **[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2cceaf80** I feel there is a step missing in my Core Graphics routines. Do I need to implement CGImageRetain somewhere?

Comment: I believe that marking your image as `__strong` will solve your problem (or, possibly, your UIImageView), though I'm not 100% certain. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my **dispayImage()** method to receive a **UIImageView** property and return **VOID**. This way, all work is done to the passed **UIImageView** instead of a localized instance and nothing is returned.

My guess is that the returned **UIImage** approach I was using before was crashing because the returned reference was deallocated the second the method completed. This also allows me to use **CGImageRelease** without any ill effects.

Here's the new approach:

```
- (void)displayImage:(UIImageView *)image
{
   CGContextRef context;
   CGImageRef imageRef = [image.image CGImage];

   CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgbaDataNew, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace,  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast ); 
   imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (context);
   image.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
   CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);    
   CGContextRelease(context);  
   CGImageRelease(imageRef);
   image = nil;
}
```

Thank you to everyone that offered help! I learned a tremendous amount just from your suggestions. This was my first time using bt and NSZombie and now I'm using them religiously! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You're releasing the imageRef, which causes the UIImage to be autoreleased.

Make sure that you retain the UIImage in order to prevent such events from occurring:

```
- (UIImage *)displayImage
{
    CGContextRef context;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgbaDataNew, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast ); 

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (context);
    UIImage *outputImage = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef] retain]; 

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);    
    CGContextRelease(context);  
    CGImageRelease(imageRef); //this line would cause outputImage to be released
    return outputImage;
}
```

Comment: I tried removing that line and I still get the same **[Not A Type retain]** error. I even tried removing all 3 of those CG..Release lines and I still get the same error.

Comment: You don't need to remove those release lines. The above code should work fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did't see the **retain** option you added. I'm using ARC and unfortunately, can't use the retain command. Is there another option? I apologize for not noting the version of Xcode I'm using earlier. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ahh ok, in that case I think you should either turn off ARC for this class, or see @Matthew Fredericks' answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `displayImage` tell the compiler you want to retain the image with `__strong`:

```
UIImage __strong *outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

or if you prefer:

```
__strong UIImage *outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```